# Is there a generally accepted name for the described property of arrow $f$?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

Let $F:\mathcal A\to\mathcal E$ denote a functor.

Let $f:a\to b$ be an arrow in $\mathcal A$ that has the following property:

For every arrow $g:a\to c$ in $\mathcal A$ and every arrow $h:Fb\to Fc$ that satisfies $h\circ Ff=Fg$ there is a unique $k:b\to c$ with $k\circ f=g$ and $Fk=h$.

(Here $c$ is not fixed.)

My question:

> Is there a name for this property of arrow $f$?

Also references are welcome of course.

I encountered something like this in "Topology and Groupoids"(page 317) of Ronald Brown. There it concerns an endofunctor $\text{Ob}:\mathbf{Groupoid}\to\mathbf{Groupoid}$. He calls an $f$ with that property universal with respect to functor $\text{Ob}$. But unfortunately I have another conception of universal arrow which is linked to concrete categories.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a morphism $f : a \to b$ is said to be $F$-(hyper)cocartesian. This is in connection to Grothendieck opfibrations. You may like to work out what this means concretely in the case of $\mathrm{dom} : [\mathbf{2}, \mathcal{C}] \to \mathcal{C}$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is a category with pushouts.

Comment: Thank you. To avoid misunderstandings could you describe in words wich category is meant by $[2,\mathcal C]$?

Comment: The arrow category.

Comment: I thought so. Now I am certain. I use a different notation for that category so I was not sure.